# Andengine Motion Streaking Resume issue

Tags: android, andengine

The MotionStreaking example given in the Andengine repository works fine, but once I press the home button and then try to resume it, it just shows up-scaled and distorted versions of the textures used in the game or just a blank screen. I need to use this in a game. Please help out...

Answer (score 0):

The MotionStreaking example uses a RotationModifier like this:

> new RotationModifier(10, 0, 7200, EaseQuadInOut.getInstance())

The rotationmodifier (internally) is making adjustments to the rotation of the textures (i.e., the setRotation() method).  When you leave and return, there's nothing to reset the rotation back to its original state.  What you need to do is create an initialize() method (or something similar) that manually sets the rotations back to zero.  E.g., something like this:

```
public void initialize() {
   rectangleGroup.setRotation(0f);
}
```